# std::async decaying(losing) rvalue reference in Visual Studio 2012 Update 2. Any workarounds?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, future, visual-c++-2012

Consider the below code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename Work>
void Test2(future<T> f, Work w)
{
  async([](future<T> && f, Work w)
                      {}, move(f), move(w));
}

int main()
{
  future<int> x = std::async([]()->int{
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(200));
        return 10;
    });

  Test2(std::move(x), [](int x){});
    return 0;
}
```

The above, fails with the following compiler error:

> Error 1   error C2664: 'void
>   Test2::::operator
>   ()(std::future<_Ty> &&,Work) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from
>   'std::future<_Ty>' to 'std::future<_Ty> &&'   c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   11.0\vc\include\xrefwrap  98  1   ConsoleApplication6

GCC 4.7.2 compiles just fine
http://ideone.com/KhMiV6

Before I go ahead and report it on Microsoft Connect:

1) Is this a bug on VC11's part or is this actually standard behavior?

2) Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

EDIT: I have reported it on [Microsoft Connect here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/785260/std-async-decaying-losing-rvalue-reference-in-visual-studio-2012-update-2). For faster resolution, you are encouraged to upvote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hm, it seems to be a bug in VC11. Apparently the implementation of `async` doesn't really forward the arguments but copies them.

From the top of my head I would create a small wrapper for the rvalue that move-constructs the element when the wrapper is copied:

```
    template <typename T>
    struct rvref_wrapper {
        rvref_wrapper(T&& value) : value_(std::move(value)) {}
        rvref_wrapper(rvref_wrapper const& other) : value_ (other.get()) {}
        T&& get() const { return std::move(value_); }
        mutable T value_;
    };

    template <typename T>
    auto rvref(T&& x) -> rvref_wrapper<typename decay<T>::type> {
       return std::move(x);
    }
```

Then you'd have to modify your test scenario, so that the lambda in `Test2` takes the wrapper instead of the `future` itself:

```
    template <typename T, typename Work>
    void Test2(future<T> f, Work w)
    {
      async([](rvref_wrapper<future<T>> fr, Work w) {
          // acquire future<T>&& here
          future<T> f(fr.get());
          // e.g. call work with future value
          w(f.get());
      }, rvref(f), move(w));
    }

    int main()
    {
        future<int> x = std::async([]()->int{
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(200));
            return 10;
        });

        Test2(std::move(x), [](int x){});
        return 0;
    }
```

Looks a little bit ugly, but at least it compiles. Hope that helps you!

Comment: Inspired by std::ref, I was thinking of exactly the same solution too. One issue to note with your code is Test2's `f` parameter will go out of scope and get destroyed by the time it reaches line `future<T>&& f = fr.get();`. I have fixed this in my own code (funny enough I had the exact same issue). I am interested to see how you will fix it. Thank you for answering.

Comment: Oh right, but you can also store a `mutable T` (instead of `T&&`) in your wrapper class and pass this around on copying. So the wrapper even has ownership of your future.

Comment: That was precisely my solution too. Please edit your answer to reflect the correct solution, so I can accept :)

Comment: Also, as a commentary and for future reference, please note const and mutable mean thread safe by the new standard. Under no circumstance is the rvref_wrapper class thread safe. It is not reusable, and it is only useful as a workaround to this issue and should be hidden away from the user, perhaps in a `detail` namespace.

Comment: @Zadirion Nitpick, but that should read "const and mutable *imply* thread safe". Herb Sutter has been changing his wording on this. The standard library requires const functions to be thread safe, but const still means "logically const" *in addition to* thread safe.