# How to move an object to a std::async()?

Tags: c++, c++11

I need move an object to a async-function to let the other function manage my resources. But it seems very difficult.
For example, I want to send a fstream to an async-function.

```
void asv(std::ofstream s)
{
//do something.
}
```

I want to:

```
std::ofstream s("afs");
std::async(asv,std::move(s));
```

It can't be compiled.

But

```
std::ofstream s("afs");
asv(std::move(s));
```

can be compiled.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 5):

That is the proper way to do it. (There is literally nothing to add to the answer)

If you are testing it with something like Coliru, note that you won't see any output from, say

```
void asv(std::string s){
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

because without specifying launch policy (`std::launch::async` or `std::launch::deferred`), `std::launch::deferred` is used and thus the async call is lazy evaluated. (It waits with evaluation until first call to nontimed wait on the returned future.)

*This assumes that you want a future, not a real thread. If you want real thread, [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) is what you want.*

---edit---
After a bit of searching I found out that libstdc++ [hasn't implemented `swap` and `move` for file streams](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011) (search for `27.9`). So, if you are using GCC or Clang with libstdc++, the answer is that you cannot do what you are asking for, even though it is fully compliant with standard.

Also it seems that Visual Studio has a completely different bug, that however also prevents this use case. For more details and possible workaround refer to [this SO question and answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140293/stdasync-decayinglosing-rvalue-reference-in-visual-studio-2012-update-2-any) *Basically, while it has implemented move constructors, `std::async` constructor copies instead of decays the arguments.*

Comment: std::async(asv,std::move(s));can't be compiled.But asv(std::move(s)); can be compiled. You may misunderstand my meaning.

Comment: @user3186766 Have you added `#include <future>` directive? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8f31d047d59ef70

Comment: Yes. I find that c++ can't pass a rvalue reference to a function<>.

Comment: @user3186766 See the included link.

Comment: sorry. I shouldn't use std::string. I should use a std::ofstream.

Comment: I mean I want to move an object to other async functions.

Comment: @user3186766 One more question, are you using GCC? If so, I'll update the answer in a bit, but you are probably out of luck. (It seems that libstdc++ hasn't yet implemented move and swap for file streams.)

Comment: @user3186766 Updated the answer with note for Visual Studio, albeit for an older version. (I tested the same code in 2013, got ~same error.)

Comment: VC++ is known to not do perfect forwarding correctly in `std::async`

Comment: N.B. the standard does not specify whether `std::launch::async` or `std::launch::deferred` is chosen when no policy is specified. GCC defaults to `std::launch::deferred` but other implementations differ.